# INSERT INTO - Subquery returns more than 1 row (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I'm trying to develop a website with PHP and MySQL. Here is my PHP code I tried:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO request_boms SET
                                request_list_id = %d,
                                project_version_id = %d,
                                amount = %d,
                                user = '%s',
                                timestamp = %d",
                                $requestNo, $bomID, $amount, $_SESSION["admin_user_name"], time());
$this->db_inventory->Execute($sql);
```

My `$this->db_inventory` variable is connected with an DB API. There is no issue with it. But when I execute the code up here returns me this:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
INSERT INTO request_boms SET request_list_id = 14, project_version_id = 429, amount = 1, user = 'admin', timestamp = 1607510083
```

I searched this issue on here (stackoverflow) but in all issues have `SELECT` statement in their queries. I didn't give any `SELECT` statement in my `INSERT INTO` query. How could it be possible?

Edit (Due to comments)

Here is my `Execute()`

```
public function Execute($sql) {
    $rs = new RecordSet($sql, $this->db_type, $this->conn);
    return $rs;
}
```

And `RecordSet`

```
class RecordSet {
    public $rs;
    public $db_type;
    public $conn;

    public function RecordSet($sql, $db_type, $conn) {
        $this->db_type = $db_type;
        $this->conn = $conn;
        if ($this->db_type == 'sybase') {
            $rsx =@sybase_query($this->sql_escape($sql)); 
            if (!$rsx) {
                $this->queryError(sybase_get_last_message(),$sql);
            }
        } elseif ($this->db_type == 'mssql') {
            $rsx =@mssql_query($this->sql_escape($sql)); 
            if (!$rsx) {
                $this->queryError(mssql_get_last_message(),$sql);
            }
        } elseif ($this->db_type == 'odbc') {
            $rsx =@odbc_exec($this->conn, $this->sql_escape($sql)); 
            if (!$rsx) {
                $this->queryError(odbc_errormsg(),$sql);
            }
        } else {
            $rsx = mysqli_query($this->conn, $this->sql_escape($sql));
            if (!$rsx) {
                $this->queryError(@mysqli_error($this->conn),$sql);
            }
        }
        $this->rs = $rsx;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made all my functions with error handling. Only this query gives an error. :/

Comment: INSERT does not return rows at all. If your code waits for returned rows then you use incorrect execution method or option.

Comment: Please show us `Execute()`. We need to see the code that causes this.

Comment: I added it. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Your query is wide open to SQL injection. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Where is your subselect? It is allowed to return exact one match, only.

Comment: We need to see the actual database code and not just some, for us, unknown abstractions that doesn't really do anything. What is `RecordSet`?

Comment: @MarkusZeller, I agree with you. There is no subselect, but how could it return like there are another rows? 

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I update it, as your request

Comment: Please add your answer/solution as an answer; don't edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved!

In my database I also have a table called `request_components`. And it had 2 primary key: `id` and `request_list_id`. After deleting `request_list_id` key from table, the problem solved. It seems to creating conflict between tables. If you had this problem, you should check your database.